# Are rows processed even when one query parameter always evaluates to false

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is an SQL statement for Sqlite and Android's Room, although this really applies to SQL in general:

```
SELECT rowid, firstName, lastName, photoUrl, occupation, summary
FROM Connections
WHERE (:wordCriteria != "") AND title MATCH :wordCriteria
```

In the WHERE clause, the wordCriteria is actually a parameter that gets set before the query is run. If it is set to `""`, the query will not return any results. But even if it's `""`, does this mean that all the rows are processed anyways or does the underlying code in the database recognize that the expression:

```
wordCriteria != ""
```

will be false and doesn't bother processing the rows?

If all the rows are going to be read anyways, is there a way to prevent them from being read if wordCriteria is `""`? I don't want to run the query if wordCriteria is set to `""`.

Comment: At least Postgres and Oracle (and most probably SQL Server as well) would not evaluate a query if the optimizer can prove that the WHERE clause is always `false`

Comment: I suspect that any decent database would do that and since it runs on a mobile device, I suspect that the database engine is optimized not to waste your battery running a query it doesn't need to.

Comment: Then... Just don't even try to execute the query if the appropriate variable is an empty string?

Comment: The example I gave is part of a much larger sql query. The rest of the query that is not shown still needs to execute. I just want to prevent executing this portion if it doesn't need to be. Perhaps a differently structured statement can allow for that but I'm clueless how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell.

SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. That means you specify **what** you want, not **how** to do it. The SQL planner and SQL optimizer are *free* to choose any option to evaluate and assess your predicates. You don't have control over it. And why would you care?

Good optimizers will probably detect the case you are talking about, but bad optimizers may not.

Comment: It will short circuit the predicate.

Comment: I see -- if the where clause contains the equivalent of `AND 1=0`

Comment: True. But since it may be difficult to know if optimization is done, is there a way in sql to at least prevent it from reading all the rows by perhaps modifying the sql statement to test for the condition before it runs the query?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the underlying database would still scan the entire `Connections` table, even if the `WHERE` clause is trying to match `title` against empty string.  If you want to avoid the query completely from your Java code, then the easiest thing to do would be to just use an `if` statement which does just this:

```
if (!"".equals(wordCriteria)) {
    // then run your query
}
else {
    // the result set would logically default to being empty
}
```

You could also check if the word criteria be null or empty, using something like `StringUtils#isNullOrEmpty` from the Apache library.

Comment: I don't think the question is about "*matching title against an empty string*" - it's about `parameter <> ''` when the value of  `parameter` is passed as `''` and the query would effectively result in `where '' <> ''`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I disagree with your comment.  I think the OP is asking whether SQLite would be "smart" enough to know that an empty word criteria would never match any row, and so the database would eschew running the query entirely.  My answer is no, in general this would not be the case.

Comment: It's not Java code. It's SQL code that is written for Sqlite and needs to be skipped inside the SQL code as it is part of a more complex query.

Comment: @AndroidDev But you're calling this query from your Android code, right?  Therefore, what would be preventing you from _not_ calling the query if the word criteria be empty?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: but the example in the question clearly uses the parameter twice. `WHERE (wordCriteria != "") AND title MATCH :wordCriteria` and if `wordCriteria` is passed as an empty string, this would result in `where '' <> '' and title match ''`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oops. That was a mistake. I updated my post. But the question still remains the same.

Comment: My answer doesn't really change.  You have some sort of prepared statement, and you would be binding the word criteria parameter from somewhere in your Java code.